# Why does contenteditable div insert a "." before the first &nbsp; tag for multiple spaces?

Tags: html, contenteditable

I haven a contenteditable div and notice if I enter multiple spaces, a full stop (period) gets rendered.

So as an example, I key in 'test' followed by two spaces, I end up with this in the DOM:

```
<div contenteditable="true">test .&nbsp;</div>
```

How can I preserve the white space for multiple spaces and not get the "."  inserted before the first `&nbsp;`?

**Update:**

I see that if I enter spaces in slowly, then no '.' gets added, so must be a timing based reason with how contenteditable works under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get this behavior. In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfrn593x/) typing two spaces however quickly does not render a period. It sounds to me like either an operating system function or browser extension. If you are testing on mobile, several mobile keyboards behave this way, typing two spaces to get a period and space. Try it with a different user agent or device, and you'll see if this is localized to you.

```
<div contenteditable="true">type two spaces</div>
```

Comment: if i key in two spaces immediately after the string you have entered I get the behaviour, tested in both Chrome and Safari

Comment: Nope, on a Macbook Pro

Comment: @mindparse then it must be your operating system. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard, then select the Text tab and uncheck box with period after double space.